# Listing of vertex-transitive directed graphs of order 4 and order 8

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

In the card game [King's Corners](https://bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/kings-corner), among others, the suits of cards stacked onto each other must be related according to some pattern. In particular, it is permissible for any red card (hearts or diamonds) to be played on a black card (club or spade) and vice versa, but it is not permissible for a black card to be placed on a black card, and likewise for red cards.

It is possible to describe this interaction as a directed graph where nodes represent suits and edges represent which suits can be placed on top of each other. The standard play for King's Corners is $K_{2,2}$, the bipartite directed graph.

Recently, my wife was gifted an "extended" deck of cards that have eight suits instead of four. I want to develop a similarly extended game of King's Corners, and I was curious as to what options there were for placing suits on each other. The key property would be vertex-transitivity (edit: and reachability from every vertex to another vertex), which would make all the suits have equal 'stackability' at the outset of the game. This leads to the question: **what are all the vertex-transitive, directed, completely-connected graphs of order 4 and order 8?**

I have used Wikipedia to try to get the right terminology to search for this, as I'm sure it's on some mathematician's personal website somewhere, but I can't find it.

It appears to me there are four of size 4, but I'm not confident the count is complete, and I'm not able to manually work out these graphs for 8 elements.

a directed cycle of length 4,

[image]

two cycles of length 4 going in opposite directions, i.e., the $K_{2,2}$ mentioned earlier

[image]

a cycle with diagonals added,

[image]

and a directed $K_4$.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by complete connectivity? And why do your graphs have directions. Do you not wish to maintain the property that if $A$ can be places on $B$ then $B$ can be places on $A$?

Comment: Vertex-transitivity is not needed for the suits to be "equally stackable" - it's enough for the graph to be regular (which in the directed case would mean equal in-degree and out-degree at each vertex).

Comment: @MathieuRundström - ah, I think I was looking for "reachability" - pardon me, my undergraduate graph theory is rusty. And no, I don't wish for symmetry - I think it would be an acceptable design to require a cycle of suit colors like black 10 -> red 9 -> green 8 -> blue 7 -> black 6, etc.

Comment: @MishaLavrov thanks! good point. I think the idea of stackability I had was that a random walk on the graph would converge to a uniform distribution, in which case you're right (today I learned). But is that also the case if we add an agent who greedily selects as many cards to be played each turn (the longest path available), given a random hand?

Comment: That would be a second, harder question, but offhand you are right that vertex-transitivity might be the right thing to ask for symmetry in longest paths.

Comment: According to my (computer) calculation, there are 58 such directed graphs. I can share the code that prints the adjacency lists if you want.

Comment: @verret that sounds like an answer to me, do you mind posting that so I can accept that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 58 vertex-transitive strongly connected digraphs, up to isomorphism. In fact, here is the number of such digraphs, for each order up to 10:

```
[ 1, 1 ]
[ 2, 1 ]
[ 3, 2 ]
[ 4, 4 ]
[ 5, 5 ]
[ 6, 18 ]
[ 7, 13 ]
[ 8, 58 ]
[ 9, 57 ]
[ 10, 161 ]
```

These were obtained using roughly the method described here:
https://symomega.wordpress.com/2012/02/27/there-are-677402-vertex-transitive-graphs-on-32-vertices/

I ran the computation in magma at http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/
Here is my code. (It is extremely unoptimised.) This actually computes the graph, not just enumerates them, so you can print out the incidence list, just remove the "//" at the end.

```
for n in [1..10] do
    GraphList:=[];
    for j in [1..NumberOfTransitiveGroups(n)] do
        G:=TransitiveGroup(n,j);
        H:=Stabiliser(G,1);
        OrbitReps:={};
        for Orb in Orbits(H) do
            r:=Rep(Orb);
            if not r eq 1 then
                OrbitReps:=OrbitReps join {Rep(Orb)};
            end if;
        end for; 
        for RepSets in Subsets(OrbitReps) do
            Arcs:={};
            for x in RepSets do
                Arcs:=Arcs join [1,x]^G;
            end for;
            NewGraph:=Digraph<n|Arcs>;
            if IsStronglyConnected(NewGraph) then
                GraphList:=Append(GraphList,NewGraph);
            end if;
        end for;
    end for;
    GraphList2:=[];
    for x in [1..#GraphList] do
        CurrentGraph:=GraphList[x];
        ok:=true;
        for y in [1..#GraphList2] do
                if IsIsomorphic(CurrentGraph,GraphList2[y]) then
                    ok:=false;
                end if;
        end for;
        if ok then
            GraphList2:=Append(GraphList2,CurrentGraph);
        end if;
    end for;
    [n,#GraphList2];
    //GraphList2;
end for;
```